# can we do a select on refcurser?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

My refcurser has the following values.

```
a = 1234
b = 5678
c = 'abcd'
d = 'efgh'
```

I need only string values from the refcurser i.e. c and d, I don't need a and b. How can I do this? My concern is wether we can do a select on stored procedure recurser.

select c, d from refcurser; // does this query works?

Comment: You've tagged this for both Oracle and SQL Server.  Which database are you actually using?  `refcursor` implies to me that you're using Oracle.  If you are using Oracle, the answer is "no".

Comment: yes, I'm using oracle

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot `select` from a `sys_refcursor`.  You can only fetch from it.

Comment: so, I have a requirement like, after values are loaded to refcurser, I need to give numbers separately and strings separately for two different REST calls, so I need to create two different sql queries?

Comment: @Naresh - If you have two separate web service calls, it would certainly seem reasonable that you have two separate SQL statements.